# How to add line below Material Toolbar in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, material-components-android

By default `material toolbar` has elevation if used inside a coordinator layout, Is there any better way to add a 1dp line or stroke below `toolbar` instead of elevation to separate it from rest of the `Views`, **Exactly the way twitter app does it?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a view to make a horizontal line

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#2d2d2d"/>
```

Put this code below the toolbar